# UITextField auto-capitalization type - iPhone App

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Is there a way to set the autocapitalizationType for a `UITextField` so that the first letter of each word is capitalized by default?

> This Is An Example Of What I Want

Comment: On the other hand - it is nice to be able to google 'UITextField capitalization' and have this pop up in 2 seconds, rather than wasting a full minute to open the documentation and scan for this.  StackOverflow IS documentation.

Comment: Stumbling upon questions like this makes me happy that 1) people are capable of asking coherent direct questions (no matter the scope) and 2) people comment the best s***

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Use 
`textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;`

For more information please read: [UITextInputTraits Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html)

Comment: It doesn't help if you past text to field. In this case delegate text input and replace first letter of each word

Comment: Would you care to elaborate some more HotJard? I d like to know how to paste a text and autocapitalize.

Comment: It doesn't work, i tried it on Xcode 6 iOS 8 Swift. I did it in code and interface builder, neither works.

Comment: @VanDuTran I noticed interface builder change worked on my phone, but not the simulator. ( XCode Version 6.2 (6C131e) )

Comment: for me in swift this worked: `textField?.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words`

Comment: Make sure the keyboard in interface builder is set to default. Otherwise it won't work

Comment: @OscarVGG with the saaaaave. Thanks. That is what was causing my head scratches.

Comment: Also make sure you have autocapitalization enabled in the os settings (settings->general->keyboard), iOS settings values override anything you set on the text field

Comment: is there any update for xcode 11.7 or 2020 :) I am getting "Use of unresolved identifier 'textField' ", thanks

Comment: @greenridinghood 'textField' is the name of the UITextField variable. Please change it to your used name.

Answer (score 40):

What we want to do is set the text field's `autocapitalizationType`.

#### Objective-C:

```
self.textfield.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords
```

#### Swift:

```
self.textfield.autocapitalizationType = .words
```

There are a few options here:

[image]

- `allCharacters` is the same as double tapping the shift key, basically capslock.
- `none` is pretty self-explanatory, keyboard will never try to capitalize letters.
- `sentences` will try to capitalize the next word after an end mark punctuation.
- `words` will try to capitalize every new word (after a space), which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

This property can also be set from the Attributes Inspector of the interface builder when you have the appropriate text field selected:

[image]

"Capitalization" is the first option in this group, just passed picking the minimum font size for the text field.

Answer (score 8):

Setting the `capitalization` property to "Words" will *suggest* that the user enter capitalized words. This can be overridden by the user by un-shifting on the keyboard. The best thing to do is capitalize the words in code:

```
NSString *text = [myTextField.text capitalizedString];
```

Comment: This will capitalize the entire string, UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords just capitalizes the first letter in each word typed.

Comment: Although this is not what the OP wanted, I really really found it useful! I had an NSString saved somewhere, which was all uppercased. I needed to compare a UITextField's text to the original string, and using your recommendation saved me from having to explain things to my user (I let Objective c do all the work : )  ) Thank you

Answer (score 8):

There is an answer for Obj-C, im here for Swift;

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.words
```

or shorter way

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = .words
```

Comment: I tested .words and .allCharacters. On the Simulator, it works. On a connected iPhone X, it doesn't. Xcode 10.1, iPhone 12.1.

Comment: I will not work if in setting -> General -> Auto-Correction / Auto-Capitalization is turned off.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. On InterfaceBuilder, on the textField attribute inspector, you can set up the Capitalization property to Words.

Answer (score 1):

You can even do that form the Storyboard or .xib file. Just have to select the textfield and in the attribute inspector on the right there is a Capitalization section where you can pick whatever suits you. In your case it's capitalisation "Words".

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.ios / Monotouch this worked for me:

```
textField.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words;
```