# How do you programmatically set a text box to capitalize the first letter?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

How do you programmatically set a text box to capitalize the first letter?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1)** You would want to set the text box's `autocapitalizationType` property:

Objective-C:

```
self.textfield.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords
```

Swift:

```
self.textfield.autocapitalizationType = .Words
```

For a more in-depth look at the options, here is a good link to a similar previous question: [UITextField auto-capitalization type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429293/3543861)

**Option 2)** You can alternatively just capitalize the first letter of the words in the string that is in the text box:

```
NSString *capitalizedString = [myStr capitalizedString];
```

**Option 3)** Since the other options capitalize every word or the beginning of a sentence, just target the first letter by the range of the string.

```
NSString *abc = textfield.text;
abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[abc substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString],[abc substringFromIndex:1] ];       
// THIS IS YOUR STRING WITH THE FIRST LETTER CAPITALIZED
NSLog(@"abc = %@",abc);
```